# How do I return a value from a PureScript function with an EXCEPTION effect?

Tags: exception, effects, purescript

I've just started learning about PureScript effects, and I'm stuck trying to make a function that has an EXCEPTION effect.

```
lengthGt5 :: forall eff. String -> Eff (err :: EXCEPTION | eff) String
lengthGt5 a = if (length a <= 5)
              then throwException $ error "Word is not the right length!"
              else a

main = do
  word <- catchException handleShortWord (lengthGt5 "test")
  log word

  where
    handleShortWord err = do
      log (message err)
      return "Defaut::casserole"
```

When I try and run this I get the following error

Could not match type

```
    String

  with type

    Eff
      ( err :: EXCEPTION
      | eff0
      )
      String
```

I understand that lengthGt5 needs to return a String wrapped in an Eff in the non-exception case, but I'm not sure how I can create an "empty effect wrapper" around the value `a`.  Am I thinking about this right?

Comment: Note that `pure` is used in lieu of `return` now https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/Differences-from-Haskell#return

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out what I was missing.  To return the value in the non-exception case, you have to call `pure a`

```
lengthGt5 :: forall eff. String -> Eff (err :: EXCEPTION | eff) String
lengthGt5 a = if (length a <= 5)
              then throwException $ error "Word is not the right length!"
              else (pure a)
```

`pure` is defined in the Applicative type class defined as follows:

```
class (Apply f) <= Applicative f where
    pure :: forall a. a -> f a
```

> Applicative is a subclass of Apply and defines the pure function. pure
>   takes a value and returns a value whose type has been wrapped with the
>   type constructor f.

So `pure` takes the value `a`, and returns that value wrapped in a type constructor - in this situation the type constructor is `Eff e`