# Error vs ErrorEvent - Use catchException in Purescript to handle an Exception

Tags: exception, purescript

I'm trying to replicate an example from the [Read PureScript by Example book](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-handlers-and-actions).

I am getting this error:

```
Could not match type

  Error

with type

  ErrorEvent
```

Here is code I have been using to try and make a POC of that example.

```
import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Eff
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (CONSOLE, log)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Exception (EXCEPTION, Error, throwException, catchException, error)
import DOM.HTML.Event.ErrorEvent (message)

grumpyGills :: forall eff. Boolean -> Eff (err :: EXCEPTION | eff) String
grumpyGills ateVegetables = if (ateVegetables)
                            then pure("Good Boy")
                            else throwException (error "Eat your vegetables")

main = do
  test <- catchException handle $ grumpyGills true
  log test

  where
    handle e = do
      log (message e)
      pure("oh well")
```

Problem is essentially the same as this example, except I get the same compile error when trying to use the code posted: [How do I return a value from a PureScript function with an EXCEPTION effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376783/how-do-i-return-a-value-from-a-purescript-function-with-an-exception-effect). I don't see what I'm doing differently.

I can see the type of [ErrorEvent](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-dom/3.6.0/docs/DOM.HTML.Event.Types#t:ErrorEvent) and [Error](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-exceptions/2.0.0/docs/Control.Monad.Eff.Exception#t:Error) are different. I can also see that [catchException](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-exceptions/2.0.0/docs/Control.Monad.Eff.Exception#v:catchException) is expecting an `Error` hence the compilation failure. I just don't see what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it.

using:

- "purescript-exceptions": "^2.0.0"
- "purescript-dom": "^3.6.0",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out I was using the wrong `message`.

I should have been using the [`message` imported from here](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-exceptions/2.0.0/docs/Control.Monad.Eff.Exception#v:message). (Control.Monad.Eff.Exception)

NOT this [`message`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-dom/3.6.0/docs/DOM.HTML.Event.ErrorEvent#v:message) (DOM.HTML.Event.ErrorEvent)

Notice the type signatures are different.. derp.

The fixed imports look like this:

```
import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Eff
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (CONSOLE, log)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Exception (EXCEPTION, Error, throwException, catchException, error, message)
-- import DOM.HTML.Event.ErrorEvent (message) -- Don't import message from here!
```

I had a second issue:

```
Could not match type
                    
  ( err :: EXCEPTION
  )                 
                    
with type
                      
  ( console :: CONSOLE
  , err :: EXCEPTION  
  | t0                
  )
```

That I fixed by adding extensible effects to my `grumpyGills` type definition.

`grumpyGills :: forall eff. Boolean -> Eff (err :: EXCEPTION | eff) String`

This would also work:

`grumpyGills :: Boolean -> Eff (err :: EXCEPTION, console :: CONSOLE) String`